# iBeacon on Raspberry Pi is configured, but why is it not visible?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspbian, ibeacon

I have followed the instructions I have found on the internet for configuring the bluetooth 4 dongle with a Raspberry Pi. I thought it was going ok. Running 'hcitool dev'' shows me the device.

So I then created and ran a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hciconfig hci0 noleadv
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e5 9f fc b0 b5 2d 11 e3 a5 e2 08 00 20 0c 9a 66 00 00 00 00 c5 00
sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv 3
```

Running the above script gave the output:

```
LE set advertise enable on hci returned status 12
< HCI Command: ogf 0x08, ocf 0x0008, plen 32
1E 02 01  1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 E5 9F FC B0 B5 2D 11 E3 A5 E2
08 00 20 0C 9A 66 00 00 00 00 C5 00
> HCI Event: 0x0e plen 4
01 08 20 00
```

I don't know if the above output indicates success or failure, but I suspect all is not well because I installed Locate iB app from Radius Networks on my iPad and added in the details above for my iBeacon and the app cannot see it.

The details of the iBeacon I entered in the app are:

```
Proximity UUID = e59ffcb0-b52d-11e3-a5e2-0800200c9a66
Major = 0
Minor = 0
Power = -59
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Paul

Comment: What model of BLE stick are you using?  Are you positive all the digits of the UUID are put into Locate for iBeacon correctly?  Can you do a cut and paste to verify?

Comment: You have an extra 00 byte at the end of your packet (meaning it does not match its embedded byte count), though that is a common mistake people have seemed to get away with so far.